# Python Foreman Issue

Tags: python, puppet, foreman

Python Version = 3.9,
Foreman Version = 2.5.4

I'm using the Python Foreman (python-foreman) module to connect to Foreman to do a bunch of automation tasks, however as soon as i'm connecting to Foreman as below:

```
from foreman.client import Foreman
f = Foreman('http://foreman-url.com/api/hosts', ('admin', 'password'), api_version = 2)
```

I'm getting a bunch of conflicting statements as below and eventually erroring out.

```
There is a conflict trying to redefine a method for a foreign resource (foreman_tasks_index):
resource:
apipie_resource: foreman_tasks
new_api: <resource:, name:foreman_tasks_index>
new_url: /foreman_tasks/api/tasks/:parent_task_id/sub_tasks
old_api: <resource:, name:foreman_tasks_index>
old_url: /foreman_tasks/api/tasks
There is a conflict trying to redefine a method for a foreign resource (sync_plans_rganizations):
resource:
apipie_resource: sync_plans
new_api: <resource:organizations, name:sync_plans_rganizations>
new_url: /katello/api/organizations/:organization_id/sync_plans/:id/add_products
old_api: <resource:organizations, name:sync_plans_rganizations>
old_url: /katello/api/organizations/:organization_id/sync_plans/:id
```

Eventually the script is erroring out at this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/data/sfreport/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foreman/client.py", line 619, in init
self._generate_api_defs(use_cache, strict_cache)
File "/data/sfreport/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foreman/client.py", line 820, in generate_api_defs
new_resource, extra_foreign_methods = parse_resource_definition(
File "/data/sfreport/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foreman/client.py", line 375, in parse_resource_definition
functions[api.name] = api.generate_func()
File "/data/sfreport/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foreman/client.py", line 282, in generate_func
six.exec(code)
File "", line 1
def lifecycle_environments_update(self, id, organization_id=None, new_name=None, description=None, registry_name_pattern=None, registry_unauthenticated_pull=None, async=None):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you pls help with this or let me know the best way to connect to Foreman API via Python to carry out the automations?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting states that (sine Python 3.5) `async` is a reserved keyword, and cannot be a variable name.  This means that the version of Foreman you are using is incompatible with Python 3.9.  Try updating Foreman, downgrading Python, or (if you are comfortable doing it) try to fix the issue yourself (changing the variable name from `async` to something else, and hoping it works).

I am not sure whether the offending code comes directly from Foreman. Try to search your code (and libraries) for `async=None` pattern, as it may also not be Foreman's fault.